How to load specific repositories only in Springboot test
I have the following that I want to do,

Set of seeder classes that I want to run one time before all tests.
Only load the required seeders and related repositories of all spring context

BaseSeeder
public abstract class BaseSeeder implements ApplicationRunner {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseSeeder.class);
    @Getter
    @Setter
    protected int count = 10; // Default amount to seed
    
    // To run seeders, pass --seed=all|<Seeder Tag>
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        if(//TOSeedOrNotLogic)
            seed(count);
        }
    }
    
     protected abstract void seed(int count);
}

Title Seeder
@Order(1)
@Configuration
public class TitlesSeeder extends BaseSeeder {
    private final TitleRepository titleRepository;

    protected TitlesSeeder(TitleRepository titleRepository) {
        this.titleRepository = titleRepository;
    }


    @Override
    protected void seed(int count) {
        Faker faker = new Faker();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Title title = new Title();
            title.setId(faker.number().randomNumber());
            title.setTitle(faker.book().title());
            title.setDisplayTitle(faker.book().title());
            titleRepository.save(title);
        }
    }
}

If I use @SpringBootTest, the seeders will run, but the whole context will be loaded.
If I used @ContextConfiguration specifying the seeders only and the required d repositories, as following
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TitlesSeeder.class,
         TitleRepository.class, })
class SpringBootApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}

I get the following error
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.TitlesSeeder required a bean of type 'com.repository.TitleRepository' that could not be found.
These repositories are simply an extension of CrudRepository interface.
Any suggestions how to only load part of the context include these repos only ?
Thanks.

Simply use @DataJpaTest this only loads beans related to JPA (repositories, entity manager, etc.), making it lightweight and focused.
@ContextConfiguration this specifies the test configuration class (SeederTestConfig) that defines beans like TitlesSeeder for testing purposes.
@TestConfiguration a nested configuration within the test class to provide only necessary beans for the test context.
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringBootApplicationTests.SeederTestConfig.class }) 
class SpringBootApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private TitlesSeeder titlesSeeder;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class SeederTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public TitlesSeeder titlesSeeder(TitleRepository titleRepository) {
            return new TitlesSeeder(titleRepository);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        titlesSeeder.seed(10);
    }
}


Simple, remove any bean, configuration annotation that you use, then write short code to initial what you want. More complex way, use profile, set each class, function or anything that you want to run in test phrase and run with test profile
@Component
@Profile("test")
public class TitlesSeeder {
}


I think @EnableJpaRepositories helps you to solve your issue.
Here is the example code snippet shown below
@SpringBootTest
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = TitleRepository.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TitlesSeeder.class})
class TitlesSeederTest {
    @Autowired
    private TitlesSeeder titlesSeeder;

    @Test
    void testSeederLogic() {
        // Test your logic
    }
}

